# Instantiate classes of an interface at server startup

Tags: java, annotations

I have a set of subscribers that need to start when server starts up. 
Right now I'm instantiating them and calling run method on them in `Application.java`.

Was thinking it would be wonderful if these get instantiated on their own, may be using custom annotation or by belonging to an interface (get all classes of interface and instantiate). This way anyone writing a new subscriber in future doesn't need to create the object and call run() on it.

Wondering if anyone has solved it earlier and whether it makes sense to do it.

Example:

I have an interface for event handlers:

```
interface EventHandler {
  void process(String data);
}
```

And then implementation classes:

```
public class CoolEventHandler implements EventHandler {

  public void process(String data) {
    //handle cool event
  }
}

public class HotEventHandler implements EventHandler {

  public void process(String data) {
    //handle hot event
  }
}
```

And I have a subscriber service which listens to remote APIs and if there's data, it passes that to handler:

```
public class PollService {

  public static void register(String API, EventHandler eventHandler) {
    //create a thread to poll API 
    //and if data is received, call eventHandler.process()
  }
}
```

At the start of my application I'm registering handlers in `Application.java`

```
PollService.register("/cool", new CoolEventHandler());
PollService.register("/hot", new HotEventHandler());
```

Tomorrow if there's a new handler, say `WarmEventHandler`, I'll have to call register again. I'm trying to avoid this last step. What would be the best way to register all classes of `EventHandler`?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague , please show some code and what servers and frameworks you use?Also, a bit detail about those subscribers.

Comment: Updated with example code.

Comment: How about using some dependency injection framework like spring or guice?

Comment: @RC. can you please explain how Spring's dependency injection work here with some example?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html. Once you have all EventHandler as bean (use the path as bean name maybe) you can use [applicationContext#getBeansOfType](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansOfType-java.lang.Class-boolean-boolean-) to do the registration. A custom annotation and some reflection is also an option